# What is the difference between budget constraint and budget line?

Tags: microeconomics

Are those things mean the same thing or they are actually different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One is an algebraic formula, the other is the geometric representation of that formula.

They are the same as much as a straight line and the equation describing said line are the same.

Comment: One could argue that the budget constraint is an inequality, while the line is (a geometric representation of) the locus of points along which that inequality binds.